# In a pairplot, how can I not show confidence intervals but display grid lines instead?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I used this code

```
sns.pairplot(data= final_df_canton.loc[:,['Median_res','Median_con','rate_internal_migration','Poberty_hogar_total',
                       'illiteracy_rate','Nro casas afectadas','zona','poblacion2016','pib','quartile']],
                  y_vars=['Median_res','Median_con','rate_internal_migration'],
                  x_vars=['illiteracy_rate','Nro casas afectadas','poblacion2016'], hue='quartile',kind="reg",
            plot_kws=
             dict(scatter_kws= 
                            dict(s= (round(pd.Series(scaler.fit_transform(np.vstack( list(final_df_canton['Nro casas afectadas']) )).flatten()),2)), alpha=0.4  )
                           ) ,height=4, aspect=1)
plt.grid()
```

My output:
[image]

I don't want to show confidence intervals in this graph. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `scatter_kws=dict(..., ci=None)`?

Comment: See [`set_style`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html) and [Controlling aesthetics](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html) about how to set a grid etc.